# Generate a file and attach it to an email on client side on a mobile browser

Tags: ios, html, mobile-safari, email-attachments

I want to use form data submitted by the user to generate a XML file which is to be attached to an email. Any ideas on how I could go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry,but I do not have the perfect answer for your problem. Anyway, if you want it to be generating the xml file on the client side, one way you can do it is using javascript. I found this thread where someone has the same objectives : [How to write data from Form in HTML to XML with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066837/how-to-write-data-from-form-in-html-to-xml-with-javascript). Hope you find something there. Good luck !