# remove node from xml and save it using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have tried the last post example which works fine with IE from this link
[How to write data from Form in HTML to XML with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066837/how-to-write-data-from-form-in-html-to-xml-with-javascript)
but i would like to add a button 'delete' to remove each time a node of xml
using Javascript or Jquery. These examples don't work for me. 
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/met_element_removechild.asp. Any one can help?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Display Emp Details</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");  
        var FILENAME='D:\\example.xml';



function SaveXMLData()
{
    validations();
}


function createfile()
{

    var file;

        var e1=document.getElementById('empName').value;
        var p1=document.getElementById('empNumber').value;
        var em1=document.getElementById('empEmail').value;
        var d1=document.getElementById('empDate').value;

        var tablemain = document.getElementById('tblmain');

    if(fso.fileExists(FILENAME))
        {
        xmlDoc.load(FILENAME);
            var lng;
            lng=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Details");

            var xmlread= fso.OpenTextFile(FILENAME,1,true,0);

            var x=xmlread.readAll();
            var replace=x.replace('</Emp>','');
            var sno=lng.length + 1;
            file=fso.OpenTextFile(FILENAME,2,true);

            file.writeLine(replace);

            file.WriteLine('<Details category="'+sno+'">');
            file.WriteLine('<SNo>'+sno+'</SNo>');
            file.WriteLine('<Name>'+e1+'</Name>');
            file.WriteLine('<PhoneNumber>'+p1+'</PhoneNumber>');
            file.WriteLine('<Emailid>'+em1+'</Emailid>');
            file.WriteLine('<Date>'+d1+'</Date>');

            file.WriteLine('</Details>');
            file.WriteLine('</Emp>');

        alert('another file updated');
        }
        else
        {

            file= fso.CreateTextFile(FILENAME, true);
            file.WriteLine('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>');
        file.WriteLine('<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cdcatalog.xsl"?>');
            file.WriteLine('<Emp>');
            file.WriteLine('<Details category="1">');
            file.WriteLine('<SNo>'+1+'</SNo>');
            file.WriteLine('<Name>'+e1+'</Name>');
            file.WriteLine('<PhoneNumber>'+p1+'</PhoneNumber>');
            file.WriteLine('<Emailid>'+em1+'</Emailid>');
            file.WriteLine('<Date>'+d1+'</Date>');

            file.WriteLine('</Details>');
            file.WriteLine('</Emp>');     

        alert('file updated');
        }

    <!-- displayData();-->

    document.getElementById('empName').value='';
    document.getElementById('empNumber').value='';
    document.getElementById('empEmail').value='';
    document.getElementById('empDate').value='';

addRow('tablemain');
    file.close();
}


function validations() 
{
    var emp1=document.getElementById('empName').value; 
        var letters = /^[\s A-Za-z]+$/; 
        if(emp1!="")
        {
            if(emp1.match(letters)) 
            {
                allnumeric();
            }
            else 
            {
                alert('Please input alphabet characters only'); 
                return false; 
            }
        }
    else
    {
        alert('Please Enter Name.');
    }
}


<!--For checking Email-->

function checkemail()
{
    var email = document.getElementById('empEmail');
        var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if(email.value!="")
    {
            if (!filter.test(email.value)) 
        {
                alert('Please provide a valid email address');
                return false;
            }
                else
                {
                    DateValidation();
                }
        }     
    else
    {
        alert('Please Enter Email.');
    }
}


<!--For checking Date Format-->

function DateValidation()
{
        var date=/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{2,4}$/;
        var empDate=document.getElementById("empDate");

    if(empDate.value!="")
        {
            if(empDate.value.match(date))
            {
                createfile();
            }
            else
        {
                    alert("Please provide valid date : DD-MM-YY(YYYY)");
            return(false);
            }
        }
    else
    {
        alert('Please Enter Date.');
    }
}


<!--For checking phone number-->

function allnumeric() 
{
    var numbers=/^\d{10}$/;
        var empNumber=document.getElementById("empNumber");
    if(empNumber.value!="")
    {
        if(empNumber.value.length=="10")
        {
                if(empNumber.value.match(numbers))
                {
                    checkemail();
                }
                else
            {
                    alert("Phone number should be numeric");
                    return(false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Phone Number should be like: 9876543210');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Please Enter Phone Number.');
    }
}



function addRow(id) 
{

    if(fso.fileExists(FILENAME))
    {

    xmlDoc.load(FILENAME);
        var x;
        x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Details");

        var table = document.getElementById('tbl');        



    var nxtbtn= document.getElementById("btnnext");
    var prvbtn=document.getElementById("btnprev");
    nxtbtn.disabled=true;
    prvbtn.disabled=true;
    if(x.length >5)
    {
        nxtbtn.disabled=false;
    }
    var j=0;k=5;
    if(k>x.length)
    {k=x.length;}

    var store=document.getElementById("txtstore");
    var maxval=document.getElementById("txtmax");

    if(id=="btnprev")
    {        
        if((store.value % k)==0)
        {
            store.value = store.value - k ;
            if(store.value>0)
            {
                j = parseInt(store.value);
                k += parseInt(store.value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            store.value =store.value - (store.value % k) ;

            if(store.value >0)
            {
                j = store.value - k;
                k = store.value;
            }

        }

        if(j > 0)
        {
            prvbtn.disabled=false;
        }

    }
    if(id=="btnnext")
    {
        if(store.value==0)
        {
            store.value=table.rows.length;
        }
        else if(store.value <0)
        {
            store.value=maxval.value;
        }
        prvbtn.disabled=false;
            if(store.value >=k)
        {
            j +=parseInt(store.value);
            k +=parseInt(store.value);
            if(k >= x.length)
            {
                k=x.length;
                nxtbtn.disabled = true;
                prvbtn.disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }

    table.innerHTML = "";
    var rowCount = 0;

        for (i=j;i<k;i++)
    {

            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "checkbox";
            element1.id =  "id2" ;
            cell1.appendChild(element1);

            // Create label
            var label = document.createElement("label");
            label.htmlFor =  "id2" ;
            cell1.appendChild(label);

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = x[i].getElementsByTagName("SNo")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

            var name = row.insertCell(2);
            var elname =document.createElement("input");
            elname.type = "text";
        elname.readOnly=true;
        elname.value=x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            name.appendChild(elname);

            var phnno = row.insertCell(3);
            var elphn =document.createElement("input");
            elphn.type = "text";
        elphn.readOnly=true;
        elphn.value=x[i].getElementsByTagName("PhoneNumber")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            phnno.appendChild(elphn);

            var email = row.insertCell(4);
            var elemail =document.createElement("input");
            elemail.type = "text";
        elemail.readOnly=true;
        elemail.value=x[i].getElementsByTagName("Emailid")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            email.appendChild(elemail);

            var date = row.insertCell(5);
            var eldate =document.createElement("input");
            eldate.type = "text";
        eldate.readOnly=true;
        eldate.value=x[i].getElementsByTagName("Date")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            date.appendChild(eldate);

        rowCount +=1;
        }
    maxval.value=x[table.rows.length - 1].getElementsByTagName("SNo")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    if(id=="btnprev")
    {
     store.value =store.value - 5;
    }
     else
    {
         store.value =parseInt(k);
    }
   }
}

    </script>
</head>

<body onload="addRow('tbl')">

    <form id="empForm" action="" method="get">

        <p><b>Emp Registration:</b></p>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="empName" maxlength="25"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone Number:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="empNumber" maxlength="10"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>EmailId:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="empEmail"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Date:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="empDate" maxlength="10"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SaveXMLData()"/></td>
                <td>
            <input type="button" value="Show Data" id="show" onclick="displayData(this.id)" style="display:none;"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <!-- <table><tr><td><input type="button" onclick="displayData(this.id)" value="Prev" id="prev" disabled="disabled"></td>
       <td><input type="button" onclick="displayData(this.id)" value="Next" id="next" disabled="disabled"></td></tr></table> -->

    <div id='displaydatadiv'>   
        </div>
    <!-- <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('tbl')" /> -->

    <div style="height: 135px; width:650px; background-color: Lavender;" >
        <TABLE id="tbl" width="350px">    
        </TABLE>
    </div>
    <table id="tblmain" border="1" style="display:true" ></table>
        <input type="button" id="btnprev" value="Prev" onclick="addRow(this.id)" disabled="disabled">
        <input type="button" id="btnnext" value="Next" onclick="addRow(this.id)" disabled="disabled">

        <input type="hidden" id="txtstore" style="display:none;">
        <input type="hidden" id="txtmax" style="display:none;">

</body>
</html>
```