# Angular 8 Create an XML file from form values

Tags: angular, xml

**Problem** I have angular 8 app that has different forms.

The user choose a form and fills it. When submit the form I need to create a `xml` file with the values from the form, that the user can download, so that he can import it to another platform. 
This app only objective is to generate that `xml` file.

So my question is: How do I do this only with angular, I don't want to develop a `node.js` api to do that or any type of back-end. Also I already search the web for it and found the `angular-xml` package but it's for converting JSON to XMl, not to generate an xml file. So how do I do this?

Comment: You can view the solution here
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6066837/how-to-write-data-from-form-in-html-to-xml-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function on the front end app that converts the form value into XML using the names of the controls as the element tags.  You can then use the [FileSaver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) library to generate and download a file from the XML string you created

Answer (score 0):

> The only way to do it is, you have to create server app to create file
> on your disk because for security reasons it is impossible to create a
> file on your disk from (angular app) or any other web app that runs on
> browsers.